# «Vencer é tudo a que aspiramos» ou «tudo ao que aspiramos»?

Tags: pronomes, sintaxe, preposições

O par de frases seguintes é perfeitamente pacífico:

> (a1) Desejamos vencer.
>   (a2) Vencer é ***tudo o que*** desejamos.

Mas como fica se usarmos um verbo com preposição? Comecemos com [***aspirar a*** no sentido de desejar (Aulete 4)](http://www.aulete.com.br/aspirar). Indico três possibilidades, com o número de resultados do Google search entre parenteses (apenas para “*tudo ao/a/o que aspiro + aspiras + ... + aspiram*”):

> (b1) Aspiramos a vencer.
>   (b2) Vencer é ***tudo ao que*** aspiramos. (5)
>   (b3) Vencer é ***tudo a que*** aspiramos. (65)
>   (b4) Vencer é ***tudo o que*** aspiramos. (49)

A lógica parece ditar (b2): ao ***o*** da expressão *tudo o que* juntamos a preposição ***a*** requerida pelo verbo *aspirar*. Os internautas parecem não ser muito sensíveis a esta lógica. E eu também não sou extraordinariamente sensível, porque (b3) é a opção que me soa melhor. A (b4) tenho quase a certeza que está errada, Parece-me que não podemos dispensar a preposição, sob pena de o significado de *aspirar* mudar de “desejar” para “sugar”. No entanto (b4) é é muito comum na net (depurei os resultados de falsos positivos como *tudo o que aspiramos a ser, tudo o que o [aspirador] aspira*, etc.)

Vejamos agora a preposição ***por***:

> (c1) Lutamos pelo futuro dos nossos filhos.
>   (c2) O futuro dos nossos filhos é ***tudo pelo que*** lutamos. (154)
>   (c3) O futuro dos nossos filhos é ***tudo por que*** lutamos. (38)
>   (c4) O futuro dos nossos filhos é ***tudo o que*** lutamos.

Neste caso a preferência, ainda que não tão marcada, é a inversa: (c2), *preposição por* + ***o***; enquanto que no caso anterior a opção equivalente, (b2), é rara. Incluí a (c4) só para ser exaustivo, pois não me parece fazer qualquer sentido. Nem indico os números, porque a maior parte dos resultados não seguem o padrão da minha frase.

Então quais são as opções corretas: ***tudo a que*** ou ***tudo ao que***? Ou são as duas? E o mesmo para ***tudo por que*** ou ***tudo pelo que***?

Comment: Tens de ir até à última página. "tudo pelo que lutamos" tem 93 resultados, contra 27 de "tudo por que lutamos".

Comment: @Artefacto O Google ao menos podia manter as proporções. Juntei as restantes pessoas do verbo para conseguir uma amostra mais numerosa.

Comment: _tudo o que_ é esquisito: http://www.clul.ul.pt/files/telmo_moia/tmoia_tesemestrado1992.pdf (pág. 75 e seguintes)...

Comment: Vê também a errata, entrada a respeito da pág. 82. Eu depois escrevo a resposta.

Comment: @Artefacto Espero que troques tudo aquilo em miúdos, que eu estou com dificuldade em acompanhar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comecemos por pôr de parte as frases 4, a não ser que queiras admitir frases como *coisas que nós lutamos*. A estratégia cortadora não é admitida na língua-padrão (exceto talvez num par de casos), e os exemplos que dás, não obstante a alta contagem para (b4), parece,-me claramente agramaticais. Talvez a alta contagem para (b4) se deva a uma confusão entre os dois predicados (*pretender* vs. *sorver*).

Em relação às outras, Telmo Móia, [na sua tese de mestrado](http://www.clul.ul.pt/files/telmo_moia/tmoia_tesemestrado1992.pdf), considera-as todas possíveis, mas marginais, independente de o pronome relativo ser ou não marcado:

> ?Tudo com o que ele sonhou realizou-se. [pág. 75]
>   ?Tudo com que ele sonhou realizou-se. [errata, entrada para a pág. 82]

Isto corresponde também à minha sensibilidade — as frases 2 e 3 causam-me bastante hesitação; preferiria certamente:

> Vencer é **tudo aquilo a que** aspiramos. (55)
>   O futuro dos nossos filhos é **tudo aquilo** por que lutamos. (85)

cujas contagens, feitas pelo mesmo método, estão entre as de 2 e 3 em ambos os casos.

---

Tentarei agora resumir (quão fielmente não sei, dado que linguística não é a minha área) as razões, segundo o autor, por que as construções com *tudo o que* são especiais.

O autor analisa este tipo de contruções nas páginas 73-82. Em primeiro lugar, nota que *o que* (e *quanto*), contrariamente a outros morfemas relativos pronominais como *quem*, não admite tipicamente antecedentes expressos, mesmo quando os morfemas estão precedidos de preposição:

> A pessoa **a quem** dei o livro aprendeu muitas coisas.
>   *As coisas **ao que** se assistiu em Díli chocaram a opinião pública
>   mundial.

Sem antecedente expresso, a distribuição é semelhante à de *quem* (pág. 74).

Com *tudo o que*, surge um padrão estranho:

> (209) Tudo o que ele disse é mentira.
>   (211) ?Tudo com o que ele sonhou realizou-se.

Se, por um lado, *tudo* é um antecedente de *o que*, então a frase (209) viola a propriedade (enunciada antes) de que as formas marcadas do operador relativo como *o que* ou *quem* não podem ocorrer em posição adjacente aos antecedente (**as pessoas quem*). Se, por outro, *tudo* não for antecedente, então (211) não deveria ser possível, da mesma forma que *com o que ele sonhou realizou-se* ou *a quem ele leu o livro aprendeu muitas coisas* não o são (o autor assume que os morfemas marcados são fruto de um processo de fusão morfofonológica entre o antecedente nulo e o operador relativo, que aí seria impossível devido à interposição da preposição) (pág. 75-76).

O autor acaba avançando uma solução em que o antecedente nulo tem um mecanismo de legimitação diferente do das outras relativas e que passa por *tudo*, com o seu traço [-humano] identificar o conteúdo do antecedente. O autor nota que esta explicação é compatível com a possibilidade de *tudo* ocorrer em posição pós-verbal (onde não pode reger o antecedente nulo) quando existe o antecedente realizado *aquilo*:

> (224) ?**Aquilo com o que** ele sonhou realizou-se **tudo**.

e também de relativas precedidas de tudo em que ocorre a forma não marcada *que* (dado que a forma marcada deixa de ser necessária para identificar o conteúdo do antecedente nulo):

> ?**Tudo que** ele disse é mentira.

Comment: Vou precisar de digerir melhor a análise to Telmo. Eu só incuí as (4) para ser exaustivo. Creio que a alta contagem de (b4) vem de muita gente deixar cair a preposição quando aspiram a infinitivos: «aspiramos ser» (300 e tal no Google search) em vez de «aspiramos a ser» (198).