# Verbo "lembrar" na forma, possivelmente, pronominal

Tags: gramática, tradução

Continuando minha jornada na criação de legendas, me deparei com algo que, baseado [no fragmento](http://g1.globo.com/educacao/blog/dicas-de-portugues/post/eu-me-lembro-disso-ou-eu-lembro-isso.html) de artigo que eu li, pode se caracterizar como o emprego do verbo **lembrar** na sua forma pronominal que, pelo que entendi, está intimamente relacionado com os pronomes do caso oblíquo.

O fragmento de frase original, apenas como referência para não fugir muito das Regras da Comunidade, seria:

> (...) because all I remember is destroying you

Minha dúvida é quanto ao possível pronome, se de fato existente, ora oculto em inglês:

> (...) porque tudo o quê eu me lembro é **de mim** destruindo você

Pois ao meu ver, também seria válido, na forma não-pronominal:

> (...) porque tudo o quê eu me lembro, **é eu** destruindo você

Afinal aquele quem fala se lembra de um único fato e a vírgula quebraria a frase em dois períodos, mas não tenho certeza se eu devo (ou posso) não usar a forma pronominal -OU- se a forma como construí a frase, pronominalmente, está correta.

Comment: ou, 'sou eu destruindo você'

Comment: Também pensei nessa possibilidade. Na verdade, antes mesmo de pesquisar sobre essa particularidade dos verbo *lembrar*, já havia traduzido, quase que por instinto, usando **sou eu**

Comment: Consideraria o contexto, podendo aceitar "te destruindo" em substituição "porque tudo o que lembro é te destruindo"

Comment: Nesse caso fica meio obscuro "quem" está destruindo a pessoa alvo do comentário

Comment: Não percebo **qual** a pergunta. É sobre se "poder ou não usar a forma pronominal", e se "a forma como a frase foi construída está correta"?

Comment: Na segunda frase não pode pôr vírgula: não podes separar com vírgula o sujeito gramatical do verbo. A conjugação de *lembrar* é pronominal nos dois casos: *me lembro*

Comment: No meu entender, perguntas de tradução estão de acordo com as regras da case sempre que o foco seja sobre como exprimir a ideia em bom português, como é o caso desta pergunta, e não na interpretação do original.

Comment: A tradução em si eu sei, mas é sempre bom ter uma base gramatical mais sólida pra não cometer um erro bobo porque, por exemplo, *mim* não faz nada, mas usá-lo não soa errado quando junto da preposição

Comment: Sem considerar o original eu poderia traduzir como: "porque tudo que me lembro está destruindo você". No sentido de ao ter recordações ruins sobre a pessoa, isso acabar causando a destruição da imagem dessa pessoa perante a outra.

Comment: @Jacinto *não podes separar com vírgula o sujeito gramatical do verbo*. Certo, porém "mim" não pode ser sujeito; nesse caso a frase é toda ela agramatical.

Comment: @Luís Ainda não cheguei a conclusão definitiva. Talvez possas ajudar:  *mim* não é sujeito; mas parece-me que em *me lembro de mim destruindo*, o *destruindo* não tem função verbal, mas sim adverbial. Tal como em «Duas vezes dei por mim mordendo os dentes»  (M. Assis, *D. Casmurro*). Também em «Não está contente ainda de ver-me arrastando assim a alma pelo pó» (J. Alencar, *A Pata da Gazela*) *me* não é sujeito.

Comment: @Luís Houve hoje uma discussão sobre este assunto no [falatório](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25826/falatorio). Talvez tenhas interesse em dar uma olhada.

Answer (score 4):

Eu traduziria a frase como `(...) porque tudo de que me lembro é de te destruir.`, e nunca dessas outras formas.
Mas talvez esta forma seja usada só em Portugal, ou não seja comum no Brasil.

Esta construção inutiliza acidentalmente a dúvida original.

Comment: Não é *tudo do/de que me lembro*? Eu sugeriria *só me lembro de*... O *all I + verbo* nem sempre passa bem para português na forma *tudo o + verbo*, especialmente quando o verbo pede preposição.

Comment: Sim, é isso mesmo. Quem fala está replicando ao outro(a) que está contando vantagem sobre si mesmo(a). Eu não posso remover o *tudo* (ou quaisquer outros sinônimos cabíveis) para não perder parte da intensidade da discussão, na qual ambos os interlocutores se odeiam (por motivos fúteis) como se pode perceber pela amistosidade da sentença

Comment: Pensei nisso, @Jacinto , mas não me consegui convencer. O «de» em «lembrar de» está em "de te destruir". De onde viria o outro de? Por exemplo, «tudo o que quero» e não «tudo do que quero». Faz sentido?

Comment: *Tudo **o** que quero é **o***, logo *tudo **do** que me lembro é **de***

Comment: Talvez este exemplo seja mais claro: *tudo pelo que combati foi*... é diferente de *tudo o que combati foi*... o *que* é pronome relativo que representa o objeto de *combati*, logo leva a preposição que o verbo exigir. Penso eu de que...

Comment: @Jacinto quase faz. `Tudo o que quero é perceber isto.` - não leva o segundo *o*; então devia ser "tudo que quero"?? Anda perder uns minutos **[no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25826/falatorio)**.

Answer (score 1):

Como dizes, *lembrar*, na forma pronominal, exige o uso preposicionado (com *de*). Este é, de resto, de longe o uso mais comum em Portugal. O uso transitivo está mais reservado para *sugerir*, *evocar*, *trazer à memória*, *advertir*. Está portanto mais próximo de alguns sentidos de *remind* (e *recall*) do que de *remember*:

- O estilo do pintor lembrava [=fazia lembrar] o de Van Gogh. (*was reminiscent of*; exemplo do [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/lembrar))
- Ainda hoje lembra o irmão com saudade. (*recalls*; exemplo [desta resposta do CIberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-sintaxe-do-verbo-lembrar-uma-vez-mais/27231))
- Esta paisagem lembra-lhe a infância. (*reminds him of*)
- Eu lembrei-o dos seus deveres. (*reminded him of*)

Os sentidos de *remember* que intersectam os de *remind* (na FrameNet, [*Remembering_experience*](https://framenet2.icsi.berkeley.edu/fnReports/data/frame/Remembering_experience.xml), *recordar uma experiência* e [*Memory*](https://framenet2.icsi.berkeley.edu/fnReports/data/frame/Memory.xml), *ter em memória*) são mais ocupados em Português Europeu pela forma pronominal. Ainda assim, podem por vezes ocorrer na forma transitiva, especialmente na literatura. Existem ainda outras regências, muitas das quais dialetais; vê a pág. 227 [desta tese](http://repositorio.ul.pt/bitstream/10451/7588/1/ulsd064381_td_Sandra_Pereira.pdf).

Em relação às tuas frases, ambas têm problemas, pelo menos na norma padrão europeia. A forma correta para *lembrar* pronominal é

> ... porque tudo aquilo de que me lembro é de o estar destruindo.

- Sobre *tudo <preposição> que/o que*, ver [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3255/vencer-%C3%A9-tudo-a-que-aspiramos-ou-tudo-ao-que-aspiramos);
- *eu o destruir* tem de estar integrado num sintagma preposicional (compara com *Eu destruí-lo é tudo aquilo de que me lembro*);
- *que*, não *quê*;
- entre *de eu destruindo-o* e *de mim destruindo-o*, a escolha correta parece-me ser *mim destruindo-o*, analogamente a *lembro-me de ti correndo pela pradaria*. A frase contudo parece estranha e aqui é melhor usar o infinitivo impessoal: *do que me lembro é de o destruir/estar a destruir*. O agente de *destruir* é então a pessoa que se recorda (ou, na forma transitiva, que é lembrada, como em *lembrei o João de o destruir* — quem faz a destruição é o João). Quando não existe essa coincidência, então uma construção com o infinitivo pessoal (*lembro-me de tu correres/estares correndo/estares a correr*) ou gerúndio/infinitivo preposicionado (*lembro-me de ti a correr(es)/correndo*) tem de ser usada.
- Em português europeu, é preciso usar o pronome acusativo *o* em lugar de *você*.

Comment: *Eu vi-me destruindo/a destruir* é possível. Não tenho a certeza que continue a ser possível se o verbo exigir uma preposição: *lembro-me de mim destruindo/a destruir*. Mas o Machado de Assis parece que achava que sim: «dei por mim mordendo os dentes» (D. Casmurro).

Comment: @Jacinto Não me parece _dar por si_ seja análogo, mas de facto eu tinha-me esquecido da pergunta a meio da resposta.

Comment: Vi no Cunha e Cintra a construção *vi-te dormindo, ouvi-o a chorar*, etc., em que o clítico é uma espécie de sujeito, que não oferece grandes dúvidas. A minha questão é se é possível ter entre os dois verbos, além do pronome pessoal oblíquo, também uma preposição. Daí a analogia entre *dei **por** mim mordendo* e *me lembrei **de** mim destruindo*. Agora nessa construção o primeiro verbo exprime causa (*fi-lo comer a sopa*) ou perceção. E aí é que a analogia poderá falhar: *lembrar-se* é capaz de já não funcionar tão bem como *dar por* neste tipo de construções.

Comment: De qualquer modo, também não gosto muito de *tudo de que me lembro é de mim destruindo-o*: é muito pesadona, seja gramatical ou não.

Comment: @Jacinto _fazer_ ou _ouvir_ são verbos que formam predicados complexos, seja marcação de caso excepcional (_fi-lo comer a sopa_), fazer-infinitivo/união de orações (_fiz-lhe comer a sopa_); os perceptivos permitem ainda o infinitivo preposicionado (_ouvi-o a chorar_). Esta pergunta lembra mais verbos como _gostar/precisar (de)_: _gosto/lembro-me de ti a correr pelas pradarias_, _gosto/lembro-me que correste pelas pradarias_, mas _*gosto-o/lembro-mo_ (não marcam caso), _lembro-me/gosto de comer_ (quem come sou eu; controlo de sujeito).